# Why does sticky nav jump when fixed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation, sticky

My website is http://southsideonline.com/

I just have an easy sticky.js that fixes the navbar on scroll, but the content below the nav jumps up below the nav bar.  Any idea how to fix this?

```
jQuery(function(){
  var menuOffset = jQuery('.menu-wrapper')[0].offsetTop;
  jQuery(document).bind('ready scroll',function() {
    var docScroll = jQuery(document).scrollTop();
    if(docScroll >= menuOffset) {
      jQuery('.menu-wrapper').addClass('fixed');
    } else {
      jQuery('.menu-wrapper').removeClass('fixed').removeAttr("width");
    }
   });
});
```

seems like its suppose to be an easy fix.  I tried using jQuery .next() to put the margin-top of the next .css after the nav to fit just under the nav like it should.  any other bright ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by the content below the nav jumps up below the nav bar? Are you referring that the content goes beneath the nav bar as you scroll? I don't see anything unusual on Chrome 36.

Comment: What browser are you using that you see this?

Comment: Nevermind I understand your question now. I can see the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap your `<div class="menu-wrapper" id="menu-wrapper">` by another `div` (placeholder) and set `height` to 84px by CSS (equals to fixed menu height) or using JS. You've met this problem because fixed elements excluded from position calculation.

Comment: Thanks man!  That was it.  In the process of fixing it for all screen sizes...  I've only been at it about a year.  On my free time, so I'm always learning. Thanks a ton!!!

Answer (score 1):

After your navigation becomes sticky / fixed, the rest of the layout moves up on the page to fill the space that the navigation was when it was relatively positioned ( or with flow initially).

Comment: This isn't an answer, this is a description of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Add a static height to your header, so it doesn't shrinks when the navigation bar gets out of the flow, something like this:

```
header { height: 117px; }
```

That worked for me.

Comment: Andrei Baibakou below was more specific.  I did set a height, but I needed to do that to a placeholder div.  Thanks though!

Comment: This worked for me because the nav was within the header. So even though the nav becomes sticky and is not included in the height calculations, the header remains the same height and therefore so does the positioning of the rest of the page elements. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with an alignment of a container (300px centre with border) which supposed to be fixed. After the content reached the container it jumped slightly  ( around 2-5 px right  ). I managed to respolve it by putting 0 margin and padding on the body in css).